# Get the rank of each string extracted from split_string

Tags: sql-server, split, outer-join, sql-server-2017, row-number

I have a TABLE with [STR DNA DATA](https://www.devyser.com/knowledge-hub/str-markers) the following Table [DYS]

---

| Id | DYS385 |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 10-19 |
| 4 | 13-16 |
| 5 | 13-18 |
| 6 | 13-19 |
| 7 | 13-17 |
| 8 | 13-18 |
| 9 | 13-18 |
| 10 | 14-19 |
| 11 | 13-19 |
| 12 | 13-18 |

I am USING the following script to split the values of [[DYS385]](https://strbase.nist.gov/str_y385.htm)

```
select top 10 id,[DYS385],t.Value 
from dys 
OUTER APPLY(select * from string_split([DYS385],'-')) t
where dys385 is not null
```

**Output**

---

| Id | DYS385 | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 10-19 | 10 |
| 3 | 10-19 | 19 |
| 4 | 13-16 | 13 |
| 4 | 13-16 | 16 |
| 5 | 13-18 | 13 |
| 5 | 13-18 | 18 |
| 6 | 13-19 | 13 |
| 6 | 13-19 | 19 |
| 7 | 13-17 | 13 |
| 7 | 13-17 | 17 |

I want to get for each Value, the Rank
example
10-19 => 10: Rank 1, 19: Rank 2

Desired results:

---

| Id | DYS385 | VALUE | RANK |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 10-19 | 10 | 1 |
| 3 | 10-19 | 19 | 2 |
| 4 | 13-16 | 13 | 1 |
| 4 | 13-16 | 16 | 2 |
| 5 | 13-18 | 13 | 1 |
| 5 | 13-18 | 18 | 2 |
| 6 | 13-19 | 13 | 1 |
| 6 | 13-19 | 19 | 2 |
| 7 | 13-17 | 13 | 1 |
| 7 | 13-17 | 17 | 2 |

Comment: I *assume* that you can't have a value like `19-10` and you would want `19` to have a `RANK` of `1`?

Comment: @HoneyBadger that's currently only an option in Azure.

Comment: Because that isn't available in SQL Server yet, @HoneyBadger , only Azure. *"The enable_ordinal argument and ordinal output column are currently only supported in Azure SQL Database, Azure SQL Managed Instance, and Azure Synapse Analytics (serverless SQL pool only)."*

Comment: Specifying the version of SQL Server when asking a question will help prevent people trying to answer from recommending things that aren't available on the version you're using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an alternative string-split method, such as XML or Json that can return an ordinal position, such as:

```
create function dbo.SplitString(@string varchar(1000), @Delimiter varchar(10))
returns table
as
   return(  
      select j.[value], 1 + Convert(tinyint,j.[key]) Seq 
      from OpenJson(Concat('["',replace(@string,@delimiter, '","'),'"]')) j
   );


select value, Seq as [Rank]
from dbo.SplitString('10-19','-')
order by [Rank];
```

[Example fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f32df3a4ce19f0a2d33c8c67ded83547)

Comment: Good, thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Given this data:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Something(Id int, DYS385 varchar(10));

INSERT dbo.Something(Id, DYS385) VALUES (3 , '10-19'), 
(4 , '13-16'), (5 , '13-18'), (6 , '13-19'),
(7 , '13-17'), (8 , '13-18'), (9 , '13-18'),
(10, '14-19'), (11, '13-19'), (12, '13-18');
```

Another way to make sure you rank the broken-up strings in the right order could be to use tricks like `PARSENAME()`, though this can be sensitive to strings lengths and whether a dot is valid within the data:

```
SELECT s.Id, s.DYS385, value = v.v, [rank] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
  (PARTITION BY s.Id ORDER BY c.c DESC)
FROM dbo.Something AS s
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(1),(2)) AS c(c)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(PARSENAME(REPLACE(s.DYS385,'-','.'),c.c))) AS v(v)
ORDER BY s.Id, [rank];
```

Output:

> | Id | DYS385 | value | rank |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 3 | 10-19 | 10 | 1 |
> | 3 | 10-19 | 19 | 2 |
> | 4 | 13-16 | 13 | 1 |
> | 4 | 13-16 | 16 | 2 |
> | 5 | 13-18 | 13 | 1 |
> | 5 | 13-18 | 18 | 2 |
> | 6 | 13-19 | 13 | 1 |
> | 6 | 13-19 | 19 | 2 |
> | 7 | 13-17 | 13 | 1 |
> | 7 | 13-17 | 17 | 2 |
> | 8 | 13-18 | 13 | 1 |
> | 8 | 13-18 | 18 | 2 |
> | 9 | 13-18 | 13 | 1 |
> | 9 | 13-18 | 18 | 2 |
> | 10 | 14-19 | 14 | 1 |
> | 10 | 14-19 | 19 | 2 |
> | 11 | 13-19 | 13 | 1 |
> | 11 | 13-19 | 19 | 2 |
> | 12 | 13-18 | 13 | 1 |
> | 12 | 13-18 | 18 | 2 |

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c07abfd0a49aeafad69c36485cf16453)

Comment: Good solution, I like it

Answer (score 0):

Split_string has an option to output this rank, called ordinal. Just add an extra parameter with the value of 1:

```
SELECT *FROM STRING_SPLIT('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.', ' ', 1);
```

That returns:

```
value   ordinal
Lorem   1
ipsum   2
dolor   3
sit 4
amet.   5
```

In your case the query would be:

```
select top 10 id,[DYS385],t.* from dys OUTER APPLY(select * from string_split([DYS385],'-',1)) t where dys385 is not null
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but ordinal is available only in AZURE sql

Comment: According to learn.microsoft.com (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) this is available for SQL Server 2016 (13.x) and up

Comment: Check [again](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#enable_ordinal), @Luc *"The enable_ordinal argument and ordinal output column are currently only supported in Azure SQL Database, Azure SQL Managed Instance, and Azure Synapse Analytics (serverless SQL pool only)."*.

Comment: @Luc No, it is not. Did you try it?

Answer (score 0):

We can also make [recursive](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-recursive-cte/) split_string function which returns the rank of each item as follows
[Link dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c1a24e3d3585dcc2b9fee0788ab17860)

```
Create function Split_Recursive(@string nvarchar(max),@delimiter as varchar(1)) returns Table
as
return(
with cte as(
select 1 N,
case when charindex(@delimiter,@string,1) =0 then @string else
substring(@string,1,-1+charindex(@delimiter,@string,1)) end [Found],
case when charindex(@delimiter,@string,1)=0 then @string else substring(@string,1+charindex(@delimiter,@string,1) ,len(@string)) 
end [MYSTRING]
union all
select 1+n,
case when charindex(@delimiter,[MYSTRING],1)=0 then [MYSTRING] else
substring([MYSTRING],1,-1+charindex(@delimiter,[MYSTRING],1)) end,substring([MYSTRING],1+charindex(@delimiter,[MYSTRING]),len([MYSTRING])) from cte
where charindex(@delimiter,[MYSTRING],1)>0),
cte2 as (select N,Found from cte 
union select 1+t.N,Mystring from cte OUTER APPLY(select top 1 N from cte order by n desc)t where t.n=cte.n
)
select N Rank,Found from cte2
)

go

select * from dbo.Split_Recursive('12-16','-')
```

**Output**

---

| Rank | Found |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 |
| 2 | 16 |